# Remove Files Based On Partial Match In Unix

Tags: python, unix

Lets say I have a file named `duplicates.txt` which appears as the following:

```
ID-32532
ID-78313
ID-89315
```

I also have a directory `Fastq` of files with the following names:

```
ID-18389_Feb92003_R1.fastq
ID-18389_Feb92003_R2.fastq
ID-32532_Feb142003_R1.fastq
ID-32532_Feb142003_R2.fastq
ID-48247_Mar202004_R1.fastq
ID-48247_Mar202004_R2.fastq
```

I want to enter a command that will search `duplicates.txt` and find any file whose name is a partial match in the `Fastq` directory and remove the file. Based on the provided example this would remove the files named `ID-32532_Feb142003_{R1/R2}.fastq`.

What Unix command should I use or if need be I could write a script in Python.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little bash function to do it:

```
lrmduplicates(){

  while read -r dupe;
  do
    echo removing "$dupe" ;

    #fine tune with ls first...
    #ls Fastq/$dupe*

    rm Fastq/$dupe*

  # dupes file: dont forget a line feed after 3rd pattern
  # i.e. end on empty line.
  done < duplicates.txt
  
}
```

For extra bonus, suppress error when no match.  Not sure how to do that myself.  `rm -f` or `rm 2>/dev/null` didnt do it (zsh on macos).

Answer (score 0):

In unix, just replace the variable character with a '?' or '.*'.

duplicates.txt

```
remove ID-?????
```

Fastq

```
remove ID-?????_????????_??.fastq
remove ID-.*fastq
```